# Modifying and rewriting .csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read information from a .csv file, change a particular row, then rewrite the file. My code is as follows:

```
import csv

forename=input("Forename:")
surname=input("Surname:")
percentage=("Percentage number:")

file=open("file1.csv", "r")
read=csv.reader(file)

sort=sorted(read, key=operator.itemgetter(0))

data = [(forename, surname, percentage, "0", "0")]


for line in sort:
    if forename == line[0] and surname == line[1]:
        condition = True
        if line[3] == "0":
            line[3] = score
        elif line [4] == "0":
            line[4] = score
        else:
            line[4] = line[3]
            line[3] = line[2]
            line[2] = score


if condition == False:
    sort.append(data)

file.close()


file=open("file1.csv", "w")
writer=csv.writer(file)

writer.writerows(sort)

file.close()
```

However, when I try to write to the file, all of the data goes into the first column, and is in the list format (["forename","surname","percentage"]).

This happens even if there is already a record with the same forename and surname (rather than changing the record, then rewriting the file), suggesting that the check isn't working either.

file.csv has the following content (it is made to store the last three percentages):

```
Cara,Day,80,30,40
Eliza,Fyles,60,37,90
Madeliene,Naylor,30,60,60
George,Hughes,34,0,0
Alice,Berger, 23,38,0
Isaac,James,50,60,85
Kyle,Lyons,22,70,35
```

What is the issue?

Comment: you want `sort.extend(data)` instead of append

Comment: could you upload sample of the input data ?

Comment: i've added the contents of the csv file @fixxxer - hope that's what you meant!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want `sort.extend(data)` instead of `append` –  [inspectorG4dget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/198633/inspectorg4dget)

Comment: http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1886/how-to-handle-unanswered-questions-that-have-the-answer-in-a-comment-or-edited-i/1931#1931

Answer (score 0):

First, your filter is not working because you are not actually modifying the fields in the "sort" object. Try a loop like this:

```
for line_num in range(len(sort)):
    if forename == sort[line_num][0] and surname == sort[line_num][1]:
        condition = True
        if sort[line_num][3] == "0":
            sort[line_num][3] = percentage
        elif line [4] == "0":
            sort[line_num][4] = percentage
        else:
            sort[line_num][4] = sort[line_num][3]
            sort[line_num][3] = sort[line_num][2]
            sort[line_num][2] = percentage
```

alternatively:

```
new = []
for line in sort:
    if forename == line[0] and surname == line[1]:
        condition = True
        if line[3] == "0":
            line[3] = percentage
        elif line [4] == "0":
            line[4] = percentage
        else:
            line[4] = line[3]
            line[3] = line[2]
            line[2] = percentage
    new.append(line)

if condition == False:
    sort.append(data)
else:
    sort = new
```

Also, I think you may have to set your variable "data" as a list instead of a tuple:

```
data = [forename, surname, percentage, "0", "0"]
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` should be a list and not a list with a tuple inside.

Like this, `['Madeliene', 'Naylor', '30', '60', '60']` and not this, `[('John', 'BAtman', 75, '0', '0')]`.

Not knowing what each step of the code is doing will probably lead to messy situations. I'd suggest you fix how `data` is constructed than change how you add a list to `sort`.

```
In [1597]: sort.append(data)

In [1598]: sort
Out[1598]: 
[['Alice', 'Berger', ' 23', '38', '0'],
 ['Cara', 'Day', '80', '30', '40'],
 ['Eliza', 'Fyles', '60', '37', '90'],
 ['George', 'Hughes', '34', '0', '0'],
 ['Isaac', 'James', '50', '60', '85'],
 ['Kyle', 'Lyons', '22', '70', '35'],
 ['Madeliene', 'Naylor', '30', '60', '60'],
 ['John', 'BAtman', 75, '0', '0']]
```